# heat equation initial boundary value problem $u_x (0,t) = u_x (3,t) = 0$ and $u(x,0) = 3 + \cos(2\pi x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The problem:

Solve:
$$u_t - u_{xx} = 0$$
$$u_x (0,t) = u_x (3,t) = 0$$
$$u(x,0) = 3 + \cos(2\pi x)$$

The provided answer:
$$ 3 + e^{-4(\pi ^2)t}\cos(2\pi x)$$

What I have done:

-----Define $ u=XT$ -----
$$XT' - X''T =0$$
-----Rearrange -----
$${X'' \over X} = {T' \over T} = \lambda $$
-----Split into two equations-----
$${X'' \over X} =  \lambda $$
$${T' \over T} = \lambda $$
----- Solve X first -----
$$X'' - \lambda x = 0$$
-----Consider $\lambda = 0$ , $\lambda = m^2 > 0$ , and $\lambda = -m^2 < 0$ -----

-----$\lambda = 0$ case-----
$$X'' - \lambda x = 0$$
$$X'' = 0$$
$$X = c_1x+c_2$$
$$X' = c_1$$

Using initial condition,
$$0 = X'(0) = c_1$$
$$c_1 = 0$$

$c_2$ is arbitrary.

-----$\lambda = m^2 > 0$ case-----
$$X = c_1\cosh(mx) + c_2\sinh(mx)$$
$$X' = c_1m\sinh(mx) + c_2\cosh(mx)$$

Using initial condition,
$$ 0 = X'(0) = c_1m\sinh(0) + c_2\cosh(0)$$
$$ 0 =c_2$$

Using other initial condition,
$$ 0 = X'(3) = c_1m\sinh(3m)$$
As $\sinh(3m)$ never equals $0$ for $m>0$,
$$c_2 = 0$$

Both $c_1$ and $c_2$ equal zero, this means there are no eigenvalues and no eigenfunctions.  Thus, let's move onto the next case.

-----$\lambda = -m^2 < 0$ case-----
$$X = c_1\cos(mx) + c_2\sin(mx)$$
$$X' = -c_1m\sin(mx) + c_2m\cos(mx)$$

Using initial condition,

$$0 = X'(0) = -c_1m\sin(0) + c_2m\cos(0)$$

$$0 = -c_1m(0) + c_2m(1)$$
$$ 0 = c_2$$

Using other initial condition,

$$0 = X'(3) = -c_1m\sin(3m)$$

We don't want $c_1$ to also be 0, therefore let $\sin(3m) = 0$

$sin(\theta) = 0$ only when $\theta = n\pi$ for $n = 0,1,2,...$

Therefore,
$$3m = n\pi$$
$$m = {1 \over 3} n\pi$$

From above, $\lambda = - m^2$, therefore,

$$\lambda = - {1 \over 9} n^2 \pi ^2$$

and

$$X = \cos({1 \over 3} n\pi x)$$

-----Back to T-----

Reminder, that $T' = \lambda T$

$$T' + ({1 \over 9} n^2 \pi ^2)T = 0$$

Therefore,

$$T = e^{- {1 \over 9} n^2 \pi ^2 t}$$

This is where I am stuck.  I don't know how to take this information and get the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution is
$$
                u(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_ne^{-n^2\pi^2 t/9}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{3}\right)
$$
The constants $C_n$ must be chosen so that
$$
         3+\cos(2\pi x) = u(x,0) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{3}\right)
$$
You can see from this that $C_0=3$ and $1=C_6$ and all other $C_n$ are $0$. So,
$$
           u(x,t)=3+e^{-36\pi^2 t/9}\cos(2\pi x).
$$

Comment: How did you get e raised to the negative $n^2 \pi ^2 t/9$ ?  I get positive. 
 Besides that, your comment was exactly the help I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: @CEP : $T'=\lambda T$, but your $\lambda$ is negative.